# Algorithm Challenge: Fuzzy Search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fuzzy-comparison

I recently took part in an algorithm challenge to create a Fuzzy search with the following criteria:

Given a set array, create a function that receives one argument and returns a new array containing only the values that start with either:

A) The argument provided
B) The argument provided but with 1 difference (i.e. 1 incorrect letter)

The array was: fruits = [apple, apricot, banana, pear, mango, cherry, tomato]

so:

- fuzzySearch('ap') = ['apple, apricot']
- fuzzySearch('app') = ['apple', 'apricot']
- fuzzySearch('appl') = ['apple']
- fuzzySearch('pa') = ['banana', 'mango']

This is the solution I came up with:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'apricot', 'banana', 'pear', 'mango', 'cherry', 'tomato']

function fuzzySearch(str) {
  return fruits.filter(fruit => 
      {
             let letterCount = 0
    const fruitLetArr = fruit.toLowerCase().split('')
    const strArr = str.toLowerCase().split('')

    for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
     
        console.log(fruitLetArr[i], strArr[i], i, letterCount)
      if (fruitLetArr[i] !== strArr[i]) letterCount++
      if (letterCount === 2) break;
    }
     if (letterCount < 2) return true
      });
   
}

fuzzySearch(str)
```

**Can anyone think of a faster way that doesn't involve iterating over every value before a soltion can be found?**

Comment: How are you measuring fast here? Big O or real world perf?

Comment: "with 1 difference" - is that like a substitution only or could it be a missing letter? would `ha` match `aha` for instance?

Comment: @tbjgolden Big O (although I would be more than happy to see a real-world perf example if you can think of one)

Comment: @tbjgolden no missing letters, it has to be in correct order.

Comment: This should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that should be slightly more efficient. Also easier to read. In this solution, I am assuming that by "difference" you mean a substitution of a letter for another letter, rather than the addition of another letter.

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'apricot', 'banana', 'pear', 'mango', 'cherry', 'tomato'];

const fuzzySearch = (str) => {
    return fruits.filter((fruit) => {
        // If our first case is met, immediately return
        if (fruit.startsWith(str)) return true;

        // Split the fruit based on the length of input string
        const test = fruit.slice(0, str.length).split('');
        let diffs = 0;

        // Compare + keep track of differences between input + sliced fruit
        test.forEach((letter, i) => letter !== str[i] && diffs++);

        // If we have more than one difference, it doesn't meet case #2
        if (diffs > 1) return false;
        return true;
    });
};

const testCases = ['ap', 'app', 'appl', 'pan', 'bp'];

for (const testCase of testCases) {
    console.log(fuzzySearch(testCase));
}
```

Slight update. Slicing the fruit is not actually necessary. We can just loop through the input string:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'apricot', 'banana', 'pear', 'mango', 'cherry', 'tomato'];

const fuzzySearch = (str) => {
    return fruits.filter((fruit) => {
        // If our first case is met, immediately return
        if (fruit.startsWith(str)) return true;

        let diffs = 0;

        // Compare + keep track of differences between input + fruit
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i] === fruit[i]) continue;
            diffs++;
        }

        // If we have more than one difference, it doesn't meet case #2
        return !(diffs > 1);
    });
};

const testCases = ['ap', 'app', 'appl', 'pan', 'bp'];

for (const testCase of testCases) {
    console.log(fuzzySearch(testCase));
}
```